# What does a linker actually modify?

Tags: linker, loading, machine-code

I am having trouble identifying what instructions will be modified by a linker and which will not. My textbook says those that will be modified are those whose value is defined as the starting address of a program +- a constant. It gives the following 2 mips examples:

1. j there # there is some label in source program
2. sw $5, result #where result is a label within the program

Then is says those that do not require modification are those whose expressions are independent of the program's starting address

1. li $l2, buffend-buffer # bufend and buffer are labels
2. bne $2, $0, exit

I;m confused especially because I thought bne was PC relative addressing, so I thought this would require a linker. I think my understanding of linkers is lacking, if someone could help me gain some understanding I'd be really grateful .

Thanks,

ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker...links...object blobs together into a final binary.  The objects are where possible position independent.  Hardcoded addresses are fine, but label based are either resolved at compile/assemble time as position independent or the linker resolves them at link time. There are other labels like external functions and global variables that also cannot be resolved at assemble/compile time and must be resolved by the linker.

It is not just instructions that are modified.  Depending on the instruction set and instruction, absolute addresses may be added and then resolved later as .rodata within .text, so not just instructions but addresses may be inserted, or other solutions.  Depending on the toolchain the linker may add instructions as well as data.

Your text/instructor may say talk about an interrupt vector table since that may be known to use external labels and as a result those labels (addresses) have to be resolved by the linker.  But that is just a simple example of the bigger picture.